# How to make table value as constant in excel

Tags: excel, sumifs, excel-365

Here I'm having the below formula.

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[Amount],Sheet2!$A$6:$A$9,Sheet1!E8,Table2[Category],Income[@Income])
```

I want to make **Table2[Amount]** as constant.

I have tried putting **$** sign before that but it was not working.

Comment: You can't do that with structured references. That's one of the disadvantages when dragging a formula to multiple columns. But you can highlight the columns and then use Ctrl+r - to copy to the right - then Table2[Amount] is fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this syntax](https://www.excelcampus.com/tips-shortcuts/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/):

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[[Amount]:[Amount]],Sheet2!$A$6:$A$9,Sheet1!E8,Table2[[Category]:[Category]],Income[@Income])
```